# Subsetting data and creating a graph with shows the best distribution

Tags: r

I have a dataset which contains gender and feelings towards feminists. im trying to separate male and female and create a graph which shows the best distribution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are more likely to get answers if you provide a short example of the code you have already tried, an example of what the expected output looks like, and specifics about the problem you are encountering.  Right now this question is too vague.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to make an assumption that your dataset is made of two columns: feelings and gender. Then you can use either of these options:

```
df %>%
 ggplot(aes(feelings,fill=gender))+
 geom_density(alpha=0.5)+
 facet_wrap(~gender)
```

or

```
df %>%
 ggplot(aes(feelings, fill=gender))+
 geom_histogram(bins=10)+
 facet_wrap(~gender)
```

The alpha is geom_density controls the transparency of the fills, the bins in geom_histogram controls the number of bins. If you don't want to have separate charts remove the facet_wrap

Comment: how do i label the axis

Comment: nvm i got it Thank you